# Process gets stuck in oSession.Logoff()

Tags: outlook, mapi, outlook-redemption

Pstcreation works properly with outlook installed.

Now, I am trying to create a pst file with standalone version of MAPI . But my process is stuck in **oSession.LogOff()**. Further if a comment that **oSession.LogOff()** line and subsequently call the **CreatePstWithRedemption** function to create an other pst, the process gets stuck in  **oSession.LogonPstStore**

```
private bool CreatePstWithRedemption(EmailJTableArgs objJTablArgs, EmailFilterArgs objFilterArgs,
                                     EmailExportRequestParams emailExportRequestParams)
{
    RDOSession oSession = null;
    IRDOStore store = null;
    RDOFolder fFOlder = null;
    RDOFolder childFolder = null;
    IRDOItems folderItems = null;
    var pstCreationStatus = false;
    try
    {
        oSession = new RDOSession();
        store = oSession.LogonPstStore(_fileName, 1, "PST");

        var folderName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(_fileName);

        if (store != null)
        {
            fFOlder = store.IPMRootFolder;

            foreach (RDOFolder folder in fFOlder.Folders)
            {
                folder.Delete();
            }
            childFolder = fFOlder.Folders.Add(folderName, Type.Missing);
            folderItems = childFolder.Items;


            var resultOfGetEmails = new ResultGetEmails();
            resultOfGetEmails.TotalCount = -1;

            do
            {
                var journalEmails = GetEmailList(objFilterArgs, objJTablArgs, emailExportRequestParams,
                                                 resultOfGetEmails);
                for (var i = 0; i < journalEmails.Count; i++)
                {
                    IRDOMail mail = null;
                    try
                    {
                        mail = folderItems.Add(rdoItemType.olMailItem);

                        // populate mail fields

                        mail.Sent = true;
                        mail.Save();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (mail != null)
                            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mail);
                    }
                }

                resultOfGetEmails.TotalCount -= BatchSize;

                objJTablArgs.PageStartIndex += BatchSize;
            } while (resultOfGetEmails.TotalCount > 0);
            pstCreationStatus = true;
        }
    }

    finally
    {
          // Do cleanup
         if (oSession != null && oSession.LoggedOn)
            {
                try
                {
                    oSession.Logoff();
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oSession);
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }

    }
    return pstCreationStatus;
}
```

**Note: The same thing works well when run in an environment where outlook is installed.**

Comment: Do you do this from a secondary thread?

Comment: Nope, there is only one thread.

Comment: How many times do you cycle through creating new session and logging off before you see the problem?

Comment: i am creating session only once . After that when a pst creation is done and logoff is called ..the process gets stuck. If logoff is not called and , i try to create a new pst with a different session then process gets stuck in logonpstStore

Comment: Contact me at Dmitry at dimastr dot com and I will send you the debug version of Redemption.