# Outlook Redemption get stuck when calling RDOSession.LogOff

Tags: mapi, outlook-redemption

I want to get emails from an Outlook Inbox. I'm using the newest Version of Redemption 5.21.0.5378 on Windows 10 with Outlook 2016 installed.

Unfortunately the Program which does that, I haven't written I just got the task to get it working. I also haven't used Redemption before.

Here is the code (I removed some lines, which I think aren't important, if you need the full method, just say):

```
        AMS.Profile.Xml mailboxesxml;
        Redemption.RDOSession rdo;
        Redemption.RDOFolder inbox;
        Redemption.RDOMail msg;
        Redemption.RDOAttachment att;

        string[] mailboxes;

        try
        {
            mailboxesxml = new AMS.Profile.Xml(appPath + "mailboxes.xml");

            rdo = new Redemption.RDOSession();
            mailboxes = mailboxesxml.GetSectionNames();
            if (mailboxes != null) 
            {
                foreach (string me in mailboxes) {

                    sserver = mailboxesxml.GetValue(me, "server", "");
                    suser = mailboxesxml.GetValue(me, "user", ""); //Environment.UserName);
                    spassword = mailboxesxml.GetValue(me, "password", ""); 
                    sfolder = mailboxesxml.GetValue(me, "folder", "");
                    stargetdir = mailboxesxml.GetValue(me, "targetdirectory", appPath);
                    stargetdir = IncludeBackslash(stargetdir);
                    sfilename = mailboxesxml.GetValue(me, "filename", "$$EntryID$$");

                    //LOGON
                    rdo.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox(sserver, suser, spassword);
                    inbox = rdo.GetFolderFromPath(sfolder);


                    Redemption.RDOItems mails;
                    mails = inbox.Items;

                    while (mails.Count > 0) {

                        msg = mails.Item(1);
                        fn = "Test"
                        msg.SaveAs(fn, exportFormat); 


                        msg.MarkRead(true);
                        msg.Delete(Redemption.redDeleteFlags.dfHardDelete);
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(msg);

                    }
                    writeLog(@"cleanup...1", 2);
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(inbox);
                    writeLog(@"cleanup...2", 2);
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mails);
                    writeLog(@"cleanup...3", 2);
                    GC.Collect();
                    writeLog(@"cleanup...4", 2);
                    rdo.Logoff();
                    writeLog(@"cleanup...5", 2);

                }
            }
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rdo);
            writeLog(@"cleanup...6", 2);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            writeLog(@"error retrieving mails: " + ex, 0);
            GC.Collect();
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
            writeLog(@"cleanup...7", 2);
        }
```

The Program successfully logon to outlook, gets the mail,mark the mail as read and deletes the mail. 
But when its calling the rdo.Logoff(); Method, it just gets stuck and not even throwing a exception.

So I never getting the "cleanup...5" log.

Maybe it something similar to this question?
[Process gets stuck in oSession.Logoff()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28021813/process-gets-stuck-in-osession-logoff?rq=1)

Some more relevant info: 
The Application is single threaded and its happening on the first run.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `GC.Collect()` before calling Logoff - you still have live Redemption objects (that internally reference various MAPI objects) when you call Logoff.

You might also want to scope variables other than RDOSession to make sure `GC.Collect()` can release them:

```
    Redemption.RDOSession rdo;
    try
    {
         MS.Profile.Xml mailboxesxml;
         Redemption.RDOFolder inbox;
         Redemption.RDOMail msg;
         Redemption.RDOAttachment att;
         string[] mailboxes;
         ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        writeLog(@"error retrieving mails: " + ex, 0);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rdo);
        GC.Collect();
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
        rdo.Logoff();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rdo);
        writeLog(@"cleanup...7", 2);
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. The Program still gets stuck while calling rdo.Logoff(). 
I forget to stop the Program and even after 23 hours, the logoff wasn't performed. 

But the logoff works, when I not login with `rdo.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox` instead using the local inbox (`rdo.Logon(null,null,null,null,null,null)`). 
But I need to access another inbox.

Comment: That is a pretty strong indication that you still have an outstanding reference... Do you have a sample project that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Because I cannot set files here, I have written you an E-Mail.